# Android text not scaling appropriately on Nexus 6

Tags: java, android, xml

I have currently been tasked with scaling the UI from my tablet device Nexus 7 to the phone device Nexus 6.

I have read the resources and information at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And what I took from it was that I was required to use DP and SP across the system for every form of sizing or scaling, I was quite happy to realise that I already had this system in place, however when I went to load it up on the Nexus 6 I found that the font sizing wasn't scaling as I'd expect in portrait, however in landscape the device seems to scale and display as expected.

**Snippet of Table Layout/Row for Buttons displayed above**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/H_btnWork"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:background="#ffc837"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:height="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Scheduled Work"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/H_btnDaywork"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:background="#ffc837"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:height="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Scheduled Attendance"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/H_btnVariation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:background="#ffc837"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:height="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Variations"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml extract**

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <!-- <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />-->

    </compatible-screens>
```

Any help tips or resources that could help me in properly scaling the UI would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to individually fine tune dimensions, the best practice is to extract the sizes to separate `/values/dimen.xml`.

so you change all the buttons from:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

to

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
```

and then you have as many `dimen.xml` file as you need like this:

`/values/dimen.xml` this is the default

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`/values-sw600dp/dimen.xml` this is used on tablet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">22sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`/values-land/dimen.xml` this is used on landscape

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`/values-sw600dp-land/dimen.xml` this is used on tablet landscape

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

important notes:

- you don't have to do all of those files, you just add the ones that you need to change. For example, a tablet in landscape, if there's no `sw600dp-land` then the system will pick from `sw600dp`, if `sw600dp` doesn't exist then it gets from `land` if that doesn't exist it gets from the default. The important is to always have a default.
- delete `<compatible-screens>` from your manifest, is not doing any good.

Comment: This is fantastic! Very well put together answer that really helped me out! Thank you so much for your time to put this together for me, it's a life saver!